# Angular 2 conditional class active in second condition not working

Tags: html, css, angular, font-awesome

I added code to show the sort direction as well as color for selected column see the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cOZPW0HKbrSPn2Vnyvom?p=preview)

- if sortable show up/down arrow: working
- if Ascending show down arrow with active color: ACTIVE NOT APPLYING
- if descending show up arrow with active color: working

Here is the code to application class conditionally:

```
<i class="fa fa-lg" [ngClass]="{'fa-sort' :  column !== 'ProjectID',  
   ' fa-sort-asc active'  : (column === 'ProjectID' && !isDesc), 
   ' fa-sort-desc active' : (column === 'ProjectID' && isDesc) }" 
    aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

See ASC and DESC both have active class which is working only with DESC true condition, please see the plunker for more detail.

Here the code after applying all conditions:

```
<i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-lg fa-sort"></i>
<i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-lg fa-sort-asc"></i> // active missing
<i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-lg fa-sort-desc active"></i>
```

Any Idea why it is behaving like this:

Answer (score -1):

Conditions in ngClass are applied in order. When the condition in ngClass is evaluated to `false`, it removes corresponding classes. If the same class is in two conditions, it might be added at first but in the next condition, it will be removed.

Possible solutions would be:

1. change style classes to `.active-asc, .active-desc {color: red;}` and then apply them respectively in the conditions;

or

2. add new condition `'active' : column === 'columnName'`